# function pageLoad not working

Tags: jquery, postback, partial, pageload, gritter

I have been struggling to get my jquery gritter notification to work after a partial postback, after lots of googling i found many suggestions recommending the pageLoad function. I'm not sure if I have implemented it right but now the gritter notification doesn't show at all, even before a partial or full postback.

Can you see where I am going wrong? Javascript/jquery isn't my strong point.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function pageLoad() {
        $(function () {
            $('.buy-notify').click(function () {
                var spn = this.attributes.getNamedItem('PartNumber').value;
                $.gritter.add({
                    title: 'Order notification..',
                    text: 'Adding ' + spn + ' to basket',
                    time: 1000
                });
                return true;
            });
        });
    };

</script>
```

Thanks in advance,

Dave

Answer (score 1):

$(function () { ... }); is called on page load, you don't need to wrap it in a function called pageLoad.

If your `.buy-notify` elements are added after page load, you might want to use `.live('click', function() ...` instead of the `.click(function() ...` binding, since `.click` only binds to elements visible to jQuery on initial page load.

Answer (score 0):

They may be referring to the jQuery shortcut for a function that runs when the page is fully loaded:

```
$(function() {
  $('.buy-notify').click(function () {
     var spn = this.attributes.getNamedItem('PartNumber').value;
      $.gritter.add({
      title: 'Order notification..',
      text: 'Adding ' + spn + ' to basket',
      time: 1000
    });
    return true;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

their is no need to do

```
  $(function () {
});
```

in a function you can do this by using onload event on Body tag in HTML like

```
<body onload="javascript:pageLoad()">
```

otherwise check pageload in jQuery  and bind the event

```
$(function() {
  $('.buy-notify').click(function () {
     var spn = this.attributes.getNamedItem('PartNumber').value;
      $.gritter.add({
      title: 'Order notification..',
      text: 'Adding ' + spn + ' to basket',
      time: 1000
    });
    return true;
  });
});
```

the third way a little bit simple that

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:iamclick(0)"></a>

function iamclick(){
   var spn = this.attributes.getNamedItem('PartNumber').value;
          $.gritter.add({
          title: 'Order notification..',
          text: 'Adding ' + spn + ' to basket',
          time: 1000
        });
        return true;
      });
}
```